# use variable between two question mark in a command option in the bash script

Tags: bash

here is two samples:
this is a sample that would cause 400 error

```
curl -i -k -u $account:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"source-path": "http://${ip}/LTMBlackList_Postbody${filename_extension}","type":"ip"}' https://$ip2$api2
```

and this is a normal one, it can get a 200 OK response:

```
curl -i -k -u $account:$password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"source-path": "http://127.0.0.1/LTMBlackList_Postbody-test.log","type":"ip"}' https://$ip2$api2
```

how could i called the curl command in script with variable?

Comment: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: I had also tried single and double quotes in the option, used another variable to indicate the option and combine them in the command. all trying cause the 400 response.

Comment: ohhh i understand in the end!!! the devil hides in the details....thanks for your sharing!!

Comment: Your title and question seem to have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: the context just list the example, the main question is described as the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$ip` is not expanded because it is in single quotes.  First close single quotes then do double quotes, expand the variable, close double quotes and conitnue single quoting.

Remember to always quote your variable expansions to disable word splitting

```
curl -i -k -u "$account:$password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT \
-d '{"source-path": "http:/'"$ip"'/LTMBlackList_Postbody'"$filename_extension"'","type":"ip"}' "https://$ip2$api"
```

Comment: thanks for your advice! but I don't understand the rule of the order in the quotes, between double quotes and single quotes. and where can i learn these basic technologies? thanks for your response!